# I get an error on discord.js v12.5.3 Mute command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I run this code it gives me an error, I've been looking around a lot on the internet for a fix of this but I just can't get it to work! Please if you would want to help me, please do!

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var ms = require('ms');

exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
    if(!msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.reply('You can\'t use that!');

    var user = msg.mentions.users.first();
    if(!user) return msg.reply('You didn\'t mention anyone!');

    var member;

    try {
        member = await msg.guild.members.fetch(user);
    } catch(err) {
        member = null;
    }

    if(!member) return msg.reply('They aren\'t in the server!');
    if(member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.reply('You cannot mute that person!');

    var rawTime = args[1];
    var time = ms(rawTime);
    if(!time) return msg.reply('You didn\'t specify a time!');

    var reason = args.splice(2).join(' ');
    if(!reason) return msg.reply('You need to give a reason!');

    var channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'potato');

    var log = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('User Muted')
    .addField('User:', user, true)
    .addField('By:', msg.author, true)
    .addField('Expires:', rawTime)
    .addField('Reason:', reason)
    msg.channel.send(log);

    var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('You were muted!')
    .addField('Expires:', rawTime, true)
    .addField('Reason:', reason, true);

    try {
        user.send(embed);
    } catch(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }

    var role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '862761416255602718');

    member.roles.add(role);

    setTimeout(async() => {
        member.roles.remove(role);
    }, time);

    msg.channel.send(`**${user}** has been muted by **${msg.author}** for **${rawTime}**!`);
}
```

And this is the error I get: (This is the error I get when I run it)

```
(node:23408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildMemberRoleManager.add (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:96:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:23408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23408) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:23408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
```

This is the code I get after 10 seconds:

```
at RequestHandler.execute (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildMemberRoleManager.remove (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:125:7)
(node:23408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: Your bot is missing the necessary permissions.

Comment: I gave it Administrator

Comment: Does its highest role have a higher position than the mute role?

Comment: Yes, and it is still not working.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to either give a role the bot cannot access (higher in the hierarchy & admin perms) or to give a role to someone that his higher than the bot in the hierarchy (i.e. the guild owner...).

Answer (score 1):

1st idea: You are giving the wrong permission of use. The suitable permission for the bot would be: 'MANAGE_ROLES', when the suitable permission for the user would be: 'MUTE_MEMBERS', I highly recommending doing this way.

```js
 if(!msg.guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES'){
    return msg.reply(`blahblah`)
}
```

2nd idea: You could be literally muting yourself, or on an admin. Test it on someone who doesn't have permission to use the 'MUTE_MEMBERS'. I really highly and strongly recommended to do it on an ALT since it can help a lot of issues.

3rd idea: The roles you are giving to your bot is not sufficient enough, maybe make it the highest possible roles in the server (like literally at the top of the server) and test it on who doesn't have perms or ALT.

4th idea: The role you have might be wrong, I highly recommend using this code:

```js
let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.get(`id`)

memeber.roles.add(role)

member.roles.remove(role)
```

or maybe your member code is wrong, try maybe doing this:

```js
member = await msg.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
```

and on error code do this:

```js
member = null
console.log(err) //so you know what errors it out here.
```

I hope these ideas help you! <3